# How can I change an array based on user in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an application uses Reactjs and Firebase, that handle users and each user can add, remove, update and of course display his favorite list. the structure for each user could be something like this `{uid: '123', favList: ['1', '2']}`. How can update the array `favList`, and doesn't add new record if the `uid` already exists?

[image]

Here's my code for adding:

```
const db = fire.firestore();
db.settings({
   timestampsInSnapshots: true
});
db.collection('users').add({
  favorites: this.state.favs,
  uid: fire.auth().currentUser.uid
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is known as an array union operation in Firebase.

If you have a reference to the document where you want to add the UID to the `favorites` field:

```
documentRef.update({
    favorites: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(uid)
});
```

For more on this see the [documentation on updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).